# Error while using tab_model() function to get an html table

Tags: r, logistic-regression, sjplot

I created a glmer model with four categorical variables, one continous, and one random intercept. Now I need to take the summary of this model and put it into a nice table in my B.A. thesis. I tried using tab_model() function from sjPlot package, however I receive an error which I don't understand

```
Error in UseMethod("family") : no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

The arguments I used were as follows:

```
tab_model(model, 
      emph.p = TRUE, 
      exp.coef = FALSE, 
      separate.ci.col = TRUE, 
      show.header = TRUE,
      show.aic = TRUE,
      string.p = "p-value",
      cell.spacing = 0.1,
      sep.column = FALSE,
      file = "model_summary_table.html")
```

How can I put my model into a nice, presentable table? Thank you for any help

Comment: The error message you get looks like one of the function arguments is not named correctly.

Comment: Yeah, apparently, the function `tab_model(model)` with arguments `show.aic` got the job done, nothing more was needed